# Open 3MF File in another Program With Macro

Tags: solidworks, 3d-printing

I made a macro a few months ago to save a .3MF (alternative file format to .STL for 3D printing) which I love, but I'd like Solidworks to Auto-open the 3MF with PrusaSlicer when the file is saved.

Is that possible? I have PrusaSlicer set as my default app for .3MF files. Can I trick SolidWorks into "double clicking" on that file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921168/how-can-excel-vba-open-file-using-default-application

Comment: Wow... I expected that to be wayyy harder than it was. Worked first time. I didn't even know that was possible with code!